# jQuery runs a function from events on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to run a function on `.change()` and `.click()` events with different arguments passed to that function. Function `foo` runs two times automatically on page load (once for each event). On top of that `.change()` and `.click()` events don't do anything when I'm trying to invoke them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function foo(bar){
        alert("This function runs 2 times on page load");
    }

    $("#some-select").change(foo(false));

    $("#some-button").click(foo(true));
});
```

I expect `foo` function not to run automatically on page load.

Comment: How do you expect run `foo()` function when you are calling `bar()` function on `click` and `change`?

Comment: Your handlers don't work because your function is named `foo`, not `bar`.

Comment: And function `foo()` will not run automatically. To be honest it wont trigger at all

Comment: It was a typo, there is `foo` function passed in my code, I fixed the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function foo(bar){
        alert("This function runs 2 times on page load");
    }

    $("#some-select").change(foo.bind(null, false));

    $("#some-button").click(foo.bind(null, true));
});
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Could you elaborate on why this works and my code didn't work?

Comment: @Jaruzel `.bind` lets you preset the value for the `this` keyword and the arguments. Your code `.change(foo(false))` executes the function `foo` immediately instead of passing the function as argument.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce the problem, but wrapping the call in a function seems to correct it for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function foo(bar){
    if(bar){
      console.log('bar is truthy, and somebutton was clicked');
    } else {
      console.log('bar is falsy, and someselect was changed');
    }
    console.log("This function runs 2 times on page load");
  }

  $("#some-select").change(function(){foo(false)})
  $("#some-button").click(function(){foo(true)});

});
```

My [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VywZJO?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you, this works well, just like @Derek 朕會功夫 solution.